# When read in from a named pipe, do char arrays automatically get a null terminator appended?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, char

I have created a struct which contains the following character arrays.

```
typedef struct {
    char id_size;
    char event_size;
    char userid[10];
    char date[6];
    char start_time[4];
    char end_time[4];
    char event[20];
} CalendarEvent;
```

I am trying to output these values to the screen after reading from a named pipe into a structue.

```
while(1)
{

    fd = open(myfifo, O_RDONLY);
            //ADD EVENT
            CalendarEvent ev;
            ev = reset;
            if(read(fd, &ev.id_size, 1) > 0){
                printf("%c\n", ev.id_size);
            }
            if(read(fd, &ev.event_size, 1) > 0){
                printf("%c\n", ev.event_size);
            }
            if(read(fd, &ev.userid, 10) > 0){
                printf("%s\n", ev.userid);
            }
            if(read(fd, &ev.date, 6) > 0){
                printf("%s\n", ev.date);
            }
            if(read(fd, &ev.start_time, 4) > 0){
                printf("%s\n", ev.start_time);
            }
            if(read(fd, &ev.end_time, 4) > 0){
                printf("%s\n", ev.end_time);
            }
            if(read(fd, &ev.event, 20) > 0){
                printf("%s\n", ev.event);
            }
            //ev.id_size = int(ev.id_size);
            //ev.event_size = int(ev.event_size);
            ev.userid = ev.userid + '\0';
            list.push_back(ev);
            ev=reset;
            close(fd);

    for(int i=0; i < list.size(); i++){
        std::cout<<"\nName: "<<list[i].userid;
        std::cout<<"\nDate: "<<list[i].date;
        std::cout<<"\nStart time: "<<list[i].start_time;
        std::cout<<"\nEnd time: "<<list[i].end_time;
        std::cout<<"\nEvent: "<<list[i].event;
        std::cout<<"\n";
    }        
}
```

However, when I run this program, I receive the following output (for just the cout):

```
Name: robert123410311608000900meeting
Date: 10311608000900meeting
Start_time: 08000900meeting
End_time: 0900meeting
Event: meeting
```

Whereas it should be the following:

```
Name: robert
Date: 103116
Start_time: 0800
End_time: 0900
Event: meeting
```

I presume this is an issue with the streams reading all the way til it sees a null terminator, but I'm confused why it is not finding one on each element of the struct and only at the end. So I suppose my question is if there is a need for me to manually append on null terminators to these char arrays? If so, would that then affect the length of the char arrays I have made?

Please let me know if there is any other information or context I can give!

Comment: No, they aren't. `read()` never does that. You could easily inspect that yourself using your debugger.

Comment: You read from pipes what was exactly written into it, nothing more.

Comment: You also should take into accouunt that `read(fd,data,n)` can read any number of bytes from 0 to n, and anything in between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When read in from a named pipe, do char arrays automatically get a null terminator appended?

The standard [`read`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read_(system_call)) syscall returns data verbatim.

This is because this call is unaware of destination types: it reads into `void*`.

You can still print those `char` arrays without having to append the zero terminator, e.g.:

```
printf("%.*s\n", static_cast<int>(sizeof ev.end_time), ev.end_time);
```

Comment: So would I have to add one extra character to each element of the struct to have a null terminator so they can be output correctly?

Comment: @RobertWhitmer This is right. Alternatively, you can print them as `printf("%.*s\n", static_cast<int>(sizeof ev.end_time), ev.end_time);` without having to append a zero terminator.

Comment: Thank you so much!